# Node.js & Express Form Submit returns 404

Tags: node.js, forms, express, file-upload, formidable

I'm trying to make a simple file upload system but everytime I submit my uploaded file I get a 404 error. I've tried various different names and paths but all of them fail instantly. When I press submit, the browser tries to redirect to `/upload` then returns the 404 error. I'm new to node.js so it may as well be very simple to solve but I couldn't find it.

I've tried 2 different modules, `formidable` and `express-fileupload`. Both return the same error.

***./views/test2.ejs***

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

***./routes/test2.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');


router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('test2');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test2.ejs');
});
router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file) {
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test2.ejs');
});

module.exports = router;
```

***./app.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("REDACTED", function(err,db){
  if(!err){
    console.log("Connected");
  }
});

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var form  = require('./routes/form');
var buttonrelay = require('./routes/buttonrelay');
var tesekkurler = require('./routes/tesekkurler');
var test = require('./routes/test');
var test2 = require('./routes/test2');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
//app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(expressLayout);
// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(expressValidator());
// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: REDACTED,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/form', form);
app.use('/buttonrelay', buttonrelay);
app.use('/tesekkurler', tesekkurler);
app.use('/test', test);
app.use('/test2', test2);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used `app.use('/test2', test2);` for the `/upload` routing
So form action should be `"/test2/upload"`

Comment: Wow, that was the problem. I'm now getting a different error but it's unrelated to this problem. Thanks a lot!